# apache poi not updating ppt file with HSLF component

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am removing slides from a ppt file using apache poi.

```
HSLFSlideShow slideShow = new HSLFSlideShow(new HSLFSlideShowImpl(dir));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    slideShow.removeSlide(0);
}
```

I printed all the slides and I saw the first five slides are gone. However when I opened my ppt file, nothing has changed. The first five slides are still there. What should I do?

Comment: You don't appear to be saving your changes back to the file - is it as simple as that?

Comment: @Gagravarr I've never seen the examples saving the changes. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you're done making changes, you need to write them out for them to be saved! The method is generally `write(OutputStream)` across all the formats, javadocs for the [HSLF write method here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlideShow.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29)

So, just change your code to something like this:

```
HSLFSlideShow slideShow = new HSLFSlideShow(new HSLFSlideShowImpl(dir));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    slideShow.removeSlide(0);
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("changed.ppt");
slideShow.write(out);
out.close();
```

There's currently no in-place saving support in HSLF, and no volunteer to add it, so you'll have to save out to a different file than the one you opened it from